# Ant run is not working due to java.exe access denied

Tags: java, ant, build.xml

I'm having a lot of trouble getting ant to run a simple program.

i'm following this tutorial - http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html

When i run "ant run" i get the following error

```
run:
[java] D:\Users\Rich\Code\Java\Standard\Workspace\HelloWorldWithAnt\build.xml:22: java.io.IOException:
Cannot run program "C:\Apps\Java\JDK\jre\bin\java.exe":]
CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

I have made sure the path to both ant an java doesn't have any spaces.

Here are my envrionment variables

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Apps\Java\JDK
JAVACMD=C:\Apps\Java\JDK\bin\java.exe
CLASSPATH=C:\Apps\Java\JDK
Path=otherpaths;C:\Apps\Java\JDK\bin\;morepaths
```

I have even tried to alter ant.bat

```
:checkJava
set _JAVACMD="C:\Apps\Java\JDK\bin\java.exe"
rem if "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" goto noJavaHome
rem if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto noJavaHome
rem if "%_JAVACMD%" == "" set _JAVACMD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe
goto checkJikes
```

All to no avail.

The below commands bring back the expected results

```
java -version
ant -version
```

Any ideas what I can try next?

update

I have used eclipse to run the build file and it works fine.
Running it from the command line still not working.

update 2

I have updated ant.bat to contain echo "%_JAVACMD%" in the :end section.
This results in the correct path to java being printed.

What on earth is going on?!
Could another application be using java?
I have tried running the command prompt as administrator with still no joy.

Comment: I don't see ANT_HOME\bin on the path.  Doubtful that is it but that is part of Ant configuration.

Comment: For some reason your java exe path does not line up with what you're showing your env vars to be: "C:\Apps\Java\JDK\jre\bin\java.exe": where is that jre coming from? What is the full output of echo %PATH%

Comment: Plus we haven't seen the ant build file either???

Comment: The JRE is normally installed along with the JDK, under the JAVA_HOME/jre directory, so the command path is correct, it is computed by Ant from JAVA_HOME. Clearly the 'Access is denied' message is delivered by the Windows OS to tell you that the user under which you are logged-in does not have permission to execute java.exe at this specific location. You should try and check the permissions and change them accordingly, or have an administrator do it if you don't have an admin account on that machine.

Comment: Mikemil - 
1) I'm not certain it is but other ant commands are working
2) The ant build File is identical to the one on the tutorial.

Comment: Rainkinz - As i understand it the jre folder in the jdk path is the private version for the jdk to use. When i installed JDK it provided the public JRE which is "C:\Apps\Java\JRE". I have read that the java path should be pointed at the JDK and not the public JRE.

Comment: Lolo - I think i'm getting the access denied error as i think the private JDK jre is being used. I will try making myself a local admin and report what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on windows, use a batchfile like that to start your ant script, f.e. :

```
@ echo off

set ANT_HOME=C:\ant193
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Apps\Java\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

: DEFAULT
call ant -f %1

: DEBUG
:call ant -debug -f %1

pause
```

If your batfile is named f.e. antstart.bat then use :

```
antstart yourbuildscript.xml
```

To increase the loglevel use :

```
: DEFAULT
:call ant -f %1

: DEBUG
call ant -debug -f %1
```

in your antstart.bat file.

Also use :

```
C:\> java -version
C:\> set
C:\> ant -diagnostics
```

to check your settings.

Comment: I updated your script to point to the correct location of Ant.
This method still resulted in the Access denied message. I ran it in debug and didn't get much from it. Would the full results help?

Comment: @rubie Do Eclipse and commandline access the same java version ?